# Zend db\NoRecordExists with multiple exclude option issue

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-validate

I have added the code in my controller to check if the record is already exists.

```
public function addAction()
{
    $form = new Form();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $role = new Role($this->dbAdapter);
        $form->setInputFilter($role->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        // start here for add validator for already exists same data as entered.
            $db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $validator = new \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists(
                array(
                    'table'   => 'tbl_roles',
                    'field'   => 'vRoleName',
                    'exclude' => array(
                      'field' => 'iRoleID',
                      'value' => $request->getPost('iRoleID') // note 1
                  ),
                  'adapter' => $db,
                    'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'This  Role is already exist.',
                    ),
                )
            );
            $form->getInputFilter()->get('vRoleName')->getValidatorChain()->addValidator($validator);
            // end here for add validator for already exists same data as entered.

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $role->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->aclRoleTable->saveRole($role);
            $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Role Added Successfully.');
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('role');
        }
    }
  return array('form' => $form);
}
```

Note 1: I have to add here second field to exclude like eDelete = "1", so if record with eDelete = "1" is there then also i can add same role name in my database.
Or give me the solution that if record with eDelete=1 is there than not show zend error and i can update it from eDelete = 1 to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do according to [ZF2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.db.html):

In your `getInputFilter()` Model function:

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select();
$select->from('clientes')
    ->where(array(
        'iRoldId' => $request->getPost('iRoleID'),
        'eDelete' => '1',
    )); 

$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name'     => 'yourfieldname',
    'validators' => array(
        array( 
            'name'    => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
            'options' => array( 
                'table'     => 'yourtablename', 
                'field'     => 'yourfieldname', 
                'adapter' => 'youradapter',
                //Here comes the magic
                'select' => $select,
            ), 
        ), 
    ),
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Zend Code of Class `Zend_Validate_Db_Abstract` which is the parent class of `Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists`, you can have string/array for 'exclude' property,

`/* 'exclude' => An optional where clause or field/value pair to exclude from the query`

so you can try

```
'exclude' => 'iRoldId = ' . $request->getPost('iRoleID') . ' AND eDelete = "1"'
```

and Zend will give result `true`.